# How to batch remove bad character from file-names?

Tags: rename, batch

I have files that had Slovak characters in them I copied them to my Ubuntu now they have these weird symbols in them, anyone knows how would I remove these character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `iconv` utility, able to convert a string from an character encoding to another, and to also perform transliteration to similar character, when the destination encoding miss them.

The following script will rename each file passed on the command line to an ascii version of the same name. Modify the variable `input_enc` if needed, and run with `--no-test` as first parameter to really rename.

```
#!/bin/bash

input_enc="UTF-8"

test=1
if [[ $1 == '--no-test' ]]; then
  test=0
  shift
else
  echo "This is a simulation"
  echo "run with --no-test as first parameter to really rename"
  echo
fi

normalize() {
  local f="$1"
  echo "$f" | iconv -f "$input_enc" -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
}

for f; do
  g="$(normalize "$f")"
  if ((test)); then
      echo mv -i "$f" "$g"
  else
      mv -i "$f" "$g"
  fi
done
```